# Efficiently transforming Arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

**Edit:** Thanks to @Felix Kling and @mario for pointing me towards named capture groups and `PREG_SET_ORDER`, I totally learned something today.

I'm curious about a better algorithm per se, though. So please just pretend that there's no `preg_match()` involved.

**Edit 2:** Abstracted question

---

While answering another question here, I stumbled upon the fact that my code for turning

this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Description text
        [1] => Different Description text
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 123.456.12
        [1] => 234.567.89
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 10.00
        [1] => 10.00
    )

    [4] => Array (
        [0] => 10.00
        [1] => 30.00
    )
)
```

into that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
        [description] => "Description text"
        [sku] => 123.456.12
        [price] => 10.00
        [total] => 10.00
    )
    …
)
```

is fugly:

```
$field_names = array('qty', 'description', 'sku', 'price', 'total');
$result_arr = array();    
$num_iter = count(matches[0]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_iter; $i++) {
    foreach ($field_names as $index => $field_name) {
        $result_arr[$i][$field_name] = array_shift($input_arr[$index]);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Maybe it is easier using named capture groups...

Comment: And `PREG_SET_ORDER` might help.

Comment: Surely, if you don't want the actual solution, this belongs on codereview.SE or codegolf.SE? (Not that it's a bad question)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Meh. I'd say that the question is broad enough to belong on SO. codereview.SE, afaik, is 'please review *this exact piece of code in its entiety*'. As for codegolf.SE, I feel that the question is much too un-golfy.

Comment: @vzwick: Well I know _you_ think that, or you wouldn't have posted on SO; I'm asking everybody else ;)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal No offense taken, just trying to explain to you (and the other potential voters) why I don't feel this should be closed/migrated :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one simpler way to produce the desired output.

```
 while (count($input_arr[0])) {
     $values = array_map("array_shift", & $input_arr);
     $result_arr[] = array_combine($field_names, $values);
 }
```

This won't work past PHP 5.3, as it requires forcibly passing a parameter by reference. (Avoiding any dumbing-down-the-language remarks here). But you can of course chop off the entries with a more elaborate manual loop at any time.

The real simplification for such cases is however [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) to turn a list into an associative array.